# Javascript sorting by numeric hierachy (extracted from div)

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a set of divs that have been cloned via Jquery ui Draggable/ Droppable.

The original elements have numeric IDs (1,2,3, etc.), which determines their hierarchy. Cloned element IDs are appended with the prefix "clone_" so that they remain unique:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="clone_1" class="clone">foo</div>
    <div id="clone_3" class="clone">roo</div>
    <div id="clone_2" class="clone">bar</div>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I sort the cloned items numerically according to their hierarchy? I can find the number:

```
var cloneID = $('.clone').attr('id');
var IDstring = cloneID.split("_"); 
var hierarchy = IDstring[1];
```

But I can't figure out the next step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getarr(a){
var IDstr2 =[];

for (var i=1;i<a.length;i=i+2){
 IDstr2.push(a[i]);

}
return IDstr2;
}

var x = getarr(IDstring);

 x.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

or descending order:  `x.sort(function(a,b){return b-a;});`

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this. Unfortunately, I'm not having any success creating the array. If you don't mind taking a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4kgGx/